# One Hot Encoding of uncommon feature levels in Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a model with a categorical factor. I encode it as One Hot Encoding using `pandas.get_dummies`.

The categorical factor has many levels that are uncommon, though. were I to re-encode the new data using `pandas.get_dummies` the new columns might be 'off' because that new level won't appear in the new data.

I was thinking about doing the following:

```
dummies_df = pd.get_dummies(list_of_all_possible_levels)
dummies_df[:] =  0

dummies_df.drop(dummies_df.index[1:], inplace=True)
# If there are 10 levels this becomes a 10x10 Dataframe. I only need
# one 'empty' row and drop everything after the first.


# Let's say the DataFrame looks like this:
df['categorical_factor', 'numeric_factor', 'other_numeric_factor']

# I want to do something where I flag the column of the feature as 1
# and append the one-row dummies_df to each row of df

for cat in df.categorical_factor:
    dummies_df[cat] = 1
    df['numeric_factor', 'other_numeric_factor'] + dummies_df
```

I'm just confused to whether I should be looping though the rows like this, or there's a better 'cartesian product'-type answer. If this were R I would just do `cbind(df, dummies_df)` since R knows to recycle the values of `dummies_df`.

Or maybe I should use `pandas.get_dummies` on the new data and join-in the missing levels as new columns like this:

```
new_dat['missing_level_1'] = [0 for _ in new_dat.index]
new_dat['missing_level_2'] = [0 for _ in new_dat.index]
```

#### Edit: Sample Data

```
levels=['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3']

A = [0,1,2]
B = [3,4,5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'levels': levels, 'A': A, 'B': B})

df = df.drop('levels', axis=1).join(pd.get_dummies(df.levels))



new_levels=['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_2']

new_A = [5,6,7]
new_B = [8,9,7]

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'levels': new_levels, 'A': new_A, 'B': new_B})

new_df = new_df.drop('levels', axis=1).join(pd.get_dummies(new_df.levels))
```

`df` is now

```
+---------+---+---+---------+---------+---------+
| (index) | A | B | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 |
+---------+---+---+---------+---------+---------+
|       0 | 0 | 3 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
|       1 | 1 | 4 |       0 |       1 |       0 |
|       2 | 2 | 5 |       0 |       0 |       1 |
+---------+---+---+---------+---------+---------+
```

and `new_df` is now

```
+---------+---+---+---------+---------+
| (index) | A | B | level_1 | level_2 |
+---------+---+---+---------+---------+
|       0 | 5 | 8 |       1 |       0 |
|       1 | 6 | 9 |       0 |       1 |
|       2 | 7 | 7 |       0 |       1 |
+---------+---+---+---------+---------+
```

(It's missing the `level_3` column.)

I want `new_df` to be

```
+---------+---+---+---------+---------+---------+
| (index) | A | B | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 |
+---------+---+---+---------+---------+---------+
|       0 | 5 | 8 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
|       1 | 6 | 9 |       0 |       1 |       0 |
|       2 | 7 | 7 |       0 |       1 |       0 |
+---------+---+---+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: You new_levels contains level_2 twice instead of level_3. Correct that and you will get level_3 in new_df

Comment: @Vaishali The point is that level_3 is _not_ in the `new_df` DataFrame. `new_df` can be something like 5000 records, but not containing the level `level_3`.

Comment: Oh so you mean that you need a new column level_3 in the new_df with all the zeros as the level_3 is not present in the column level?

Comment: Have you considered feature hashing?  It maps categorical values to columns indices, but you don't need to have seen all possible categorical values in your training data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most stable solution is to `reindex` the dataframe of dummies.

When you encode the first (prototype) dataframe, you remember the list of dummy columns:

```
# the initial encoding
levels=['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3']
df_original = pd.DataFrame({'levels': levels, 'A': [0,1,2], 'B': [3,4,5]})
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df_original.levels)
df = df_original.drop('levels', axis=1).join(dummies)
# remember the levels and their order
dummy_columns = list(dummies.columns)
```

After that, you force your new dummy dataframe to have the same columns:

```
# encoding another dataframe
new_levels=['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_2']
new_df_original = pd.DataFrame({'levels': new_levels, 'A': [5,6,7], 'B': [8,9,7]})
# this is where I use the remembered information
new_dummies = pd.get_dummies(new_df_original.levels). \
    reindex(columns=dummy_columns).fillna(0).astype(int)
new_df = new_df_original.drop('levels', axis=1).join(new_dummies)
print(new_df)
```

And it gives the result you wanted:

```
   A  B  level_1  level_2  level_3
0  5  8        1        0        0
1  6  9        0        1        0
2  7  7        0        1        0
```